# Determine the values ​of k that make the equation a circle.

Tags: calculus, circles

Given the equation: $$(2x^2) + (2y^2) + 4kx - 2y = 2k - 8$$

Find the values of k that make the equation a circle.

My question is what is the procedure for reaching this conclusion:

Answer: $k \in (-\infty, -5/2) \cup (3/2, +\infty)$

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

Complete the squares to get

$2x^2+4kx+2k^2+2y^2-2y+\frac12=2k-8+2k^2+\frac12=\frac12(2k-3)(2k+5)$,

and, to get a circle, the right side must be positive.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, but I still can't understand where 1/2 (2k - 3)(2k + 5) comes from...

Comment: You need to add some constant terms to complete the squares. What you are trying to accomplish is to write $$(x-x_c(k))^2+(y-y_c(k))^2=R^2(k)$$
All $x_c, y_c, R$ are independent of $x$ and $y$. Finally, you want $R^2>0$

Comment: Where the $\frac12(2k-3)(2k+5)$ comes from, @Rad:  We had $2k-8$ on the right side; we added $2k^2+\frac12$ to both sides to complete the squares on the left side; and $2k-8+2k^2+\frac12=\frac12(2k-3)(2k+5)$

Comment: Thank you both so much! I got away with it.

Answer (score 1):

$$(2x^2) + (2y^2) + 4kx - 2y = 2k - 8\\
x^2+y^2+2kx-y=k-4\\
(x+k)^2-k^2+(y-\frac12)^2-\frac14=k-4\\
(x+k)^2+(y-\frac12)^2=k^2+\frac14+k-4\\f(x,y)>0\\
k^2+\frac14+k-4>0$$

Comment: Hi: welcome to MSE, As a first try was a good latex writing